# Получить место пользователя в рейтинге

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Есть uid пользователя равняется 3. Нужно определить по сортировки по полю lv2 что данный пользователь с uid=3, занимает второе место. Если просто отсортировать, в ручную в графическом видео видно, что второе, а как составить такой sql запрос. База данных MySql

```
SELECT * FROM `testdb` ORDER BY `testdb`.`lv` DESC
```

Вот такой запрос просто выводит всех пользователей. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/rank_based_on_score

Comment: ROW_NUMBER в CTE либо подзапросе. Либо коррелированный подзапрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM testdb t2
            WHERE t1.lv <= t2.lv) place
FROM testdb t1
WHERE uid = 3
```

Или так:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lv DESC) place
    FROM testdb
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE uid = 3
```

Оба запроса предполагают, что `lv` не имеет дубликатов. Иначе надо вводить доп. критерии.

Comment: Вроде нормально, спасибо